# How to send verification email with Link in AWS cognito to redirect for confirmation (signup confirm, forgot password confirm) without using Lambda

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

After signup or forgot password user should receive a mail and If the user clicks the above link it will redirect to confirmation page of website

In my reactjs website, I tried signupConfirm but it sending email only with verification code
But i expected verification link inside email which redirects and autopopulate the verification code not manual

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, aws-cognito Updated this feature
Earlier I was tired of going through all the answers asked on StackOverflow and other platforms where everyone was talking about Lambda solutions only but now you don't need to use Lambda.

here you can send a customized email with the verification link AWS-Cognito docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-settings-email-verification-message-customization.html